# SwiftUI Sudoku Generator - Fatal Error: Index Out of Range

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, swiftui, sudoku

I'm working on a Sudoku game using SwiftUI. I have a SudokuGenerator class that generates a valid Sudoku grid, then removes a certain number of cells based on the difficulty level. The generation process involves filling the diagonal of the Sudoku grid with non-repeating digits, then filling the remaining blocks. The grid is a 2D array of Ints.

Here is the code for my SudokuGenerator class:

```
class SudokuGenerator: ObservableObject {
    @Published var grid: [[Int]] = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: 9), count: 9)
    // other properties and methods for generating Sudoku ...

    func generateGrid(k: Int) -> [[Int]] {
        fillDiagonal()
        fillRemaining(i: 0, j: 3)
        fillRemaining(i: 3, j: 0)
        removeKDigits(k: k)
        return grid
    }

    // ... other functions for Sudoku generation ...
}
```

`
Here is the code where I use the Sudoku Generator in my view model:

```
class EnigmaViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var grid: [[Int]] = []

    let difficulty = Difficulty.easy

    func generateSudoku() {
        let generator = SudokuGenerator()
        self.grid = generator.generateGrid(k: 20)
    }
}
```

However, when I run the app, I get a runtime error: "Fatal error: Index out of range."

In the debug navigator, I see errors pointing to lines where I access elements of the grid array. For instance:

```
    if grid[row][col] != 0 {
```

and

```
ZStack {
```

I am not sure why I'm getting an index out of range error when it seems I'm working within the bounds of the array.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

In my SwiftUI project, I am implementing a Sudoku game. For this, I've created a SudokuGenerator class that generates Sudoku puzzles.

The generateGrid function within SudokuGenerator is supposed to generate a Sudoku grid with a specified number of clues (cells filled with numbers). The Sudoku grid is a 2D array of integers. The generateGrid function is supposed to fill in the 2D array with a valid Sudoku puzzle and return this 2D array.

In my EnigmaViewModel class, I have a generateSudoku function which is supposed to call the generateGrid function from SudokuGenerator and assign the resulting 2D array to the grid property of EnigmaViewModel.

I am expecting the generateSudoku function to successfully generate a Sudoku puzzle and assign it to grid. However, when I run my code, the app crashes with a "Fatal error: Index out of range" error. The console and debugger do not provide a clear indication of where this error is happening.

I tried to debug the issue by placing print statements in my code to see how far the execution goes before it crashes, but this did not help me pinpoint the problem. I am looking for help to understand why this "Index out of range" error is happening and how I can fix it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. In order to have someone help debug this properly, you'd need to include a [mre]. You've included snippets of the code and the error is very clear what's going wrong, but there's no way to concretely say what the solution is since you haven't included the relevant code.